# Replacing field values in a fixed-position file using awk

Tags: awk, text-processing

The ask here is to replace position 9-12 with a blank, for example, in all fixed-sized records.

I used

```
cat file | awk '{sub(substr($0,9,12),"   ",$0);print}'
```

Works, unless there is a blank preceding position 9. Tried to indicate the delimiter like this

```
cat file | awk -F"|" '{sub(substr($0,9,12),"   ",$0);print}'
```

Did not help. What would be the right syntax here?

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you'll take sed instead, `sed 's/^\(.\{8\}\).\{4\}/\1    /'` is standard; many sed's today have `-r` or `-E` for 'extended' regexp then you can drop the backslashes

Comment: You do not need `cat` here, GNU `awk` can read files itself, your 1st code is equivalent to `awk '{sub(substr($0,9,12),"   ",$0);print}' file`, setting field separator does affect how line is split into lines, but not whole line (`$0`) therefore both your codes will give same output, also your code will malfunction for lines having less than 9 characters, by prefixed them with spaces, this might be not problem if all lines are long enough, but if it is so, that should be implicitly given in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample file:

```
$ cat file
1234567890123456
1234567 90123456
1234567890123456
1234567 90123456
1234567890123456
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '{ print substr($0,1,8) "    " substr($0,13) }' file
```

**NOTES:**

- this replaces ***each*** of the 9th-12th positions with a space (ie, replace the 4 fields with a total of 4 spaces)
- if the intention is to replace the 4 fields with a single space then replace the `"    "` with `" "`

This generates:

```
12345678    3456
1234567     3456
12345678    3456
1234567     3456
12345678    3456
```

---

Using the same idea to process the positions dynamically (similar to Cyrus suggestion in comments):

```
awk -v start=9 -v end=12 '{ print substr($0,1,start-1) sprintf("%*s",(end-start+1)," ") substr($0,end+1) }' file
```

This also generates:

```
12345678    3456
1234567     3456
12345678    3456
1234567     3456
12345678    3456
```

Comment: or `awk -v start=9 -v end=12 '{ printf("%s", substr($0, 1, start-1)); for(i=start; i<=end; i++) printf("%s", " "); print substr($0, end+1) }' file`

Comment: Mark's solution worked, have not checked Cyrus's yet. And thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown attempts please try following GNU `awk` code. Using `match` function in `awk` program where using regex `(^.{8}).{4}(.*$)` which creates 2 capturing group and it contains value into array arr and then printing 1st and 2nd element of array arr.

```
awk '
match($0,/(^.{8}).{4}(.*$)/,arr){
  print arr[1]"    "arr[2]
}
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU AWK

```
$ awk -v from=9 -v to=12 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}{for(i=from;i<=to;i++) $i=" "}1' file
```

Comment: Or `gawk -vFIELDWIDTHS="8 4 9999" -vOFS= '$2="    "'`